# sparksql drop hive table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to drop a hive table through sparksql.

In a cluster with hadoop 2.6, hive 2.0, spark 1.6 and spark 2.0 installed. I tried the following code in pyspark shell and spark-submit job with both version.

```
sqlContext.sql('drop table test')  //spark 1.6
spark.sql('drop table test')       //spark 2.0
```

Both code works fine in pyspark-shell , I can see from the hive cli that the ***test*** table no longer exist.

However, if the code was in a python file and later submitted to cluster using spark-submit, the code never took effect.

spark 2.0 even gave error about

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Table to drop '`try`' does not exist;"
```

I have copied **hive-site.xml** into the conf directory in spark.

What would be the correct way to drop a hive table through sparksql?

Update:

I tried compared the spark environment between the spark-shell and the job I submitted using the following code

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster try_spark_sql.py
```

In the spark-shell environment, I can see **spark.sql.catalogImplementation**   is set to **hive**

IN the job submitted using the above code. The environment doesn't contain **spark.sql.catalogImplementation**
I tried setting it using the following code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PythonSQL").config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation","hive").
```

But it doesn't have any effect on the environment.

One workaround I found is submitting the job using **client** mode instead of **cluster** mode. Then the hive table can be successfully dropped.

Comment: Question, are you using sqlContext context in your spark-submit script?

Comment: of course, I didn't add that part of the code. The sparkcontx is initialized as usual and using sqllContxt.sql can read from .orc file sucessfully.

Answer (score 10):

When you are using PySpark shell, Spark has inbuilt Hive support, the default SQLContext implementation (the one available as a sqlContext) is HiveContext.

In your application if you are using plain SQLContext which doesn't provide Hive capabilities.

Please do as below , it should work.

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql('drop table test')
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply since I was on  a holiday. I rechecked my code and found `sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)` already there though I didn't have`from pyspark.sql import HiveContext`. After adding the line of code, spark still complain `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Table to drop '`try`' does not exist;"` . Perhaps it's because the cluster is comfigured using spark 2.0.

Comment: But I found a wield work around for now. Submit the job using `--mode client ` instead of `--mode cluster` can successfully drop the table.

Answer (score 6):

From the error it is quite clear that the table does not exist in the current database you are using. You need to change your SQL as follows:

```
sqlContext.sql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db_name.table_name')  //spark 1.6
spark.sql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db_name.table_name')       //spark 2.0
```

Any SQL query executed with `HiveContext` in Spark 1.6 or `SparkSession` in Spark 2.0, searches for the table in Hives' **default** database. We need to either execute the query `spark.sql("USE db_name")` and then execute the SQL specific to the table or **prefix the name of the Database** with the **name of the Table** (e.g `testDB.testTable`) for the query to execute properly as shown above.

Comment: How can we get a return value for `sqlContext.sql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db_name.table_name')`? I want to know whether the command was successfully executed or not.

Comment: With Spark 2.0, we can use sparkSession.catalog.listTables() which returns a Dataset[Table] containing all tables in given database or spark.catalog.tableExists which returns a Boolean

Answer (score 5):

Slight change...This worked for me:

```
spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name")
```

Comment: spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name")