# Delete data from Hive table using SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use

```
alter table drop if exists partition
```

statement to delete data in **Hive table**.

What would happen if .Trash folder is full? Will the alter table statement just fail silently? What's the workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete and update a record in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810537/how-to-delete-and-update-a-record-in-hive)

Comment: i'm using sparksql, not hive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sparksql drop hive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787792/sparksql-drop-hive-table)

Comment: @Bahubali i'm trying to drop partitions of a hive table, not dropping the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

If the hive table is `external` then the drop partition will only remove the reference in the metastore, leaving the filesystem data intact.

If it's a `managed` table, then both will be removed. When `purge` keyword is added it will skip the `.trash` folder

```
ALTER TABLE table_identifier DROP [ IF EXISTS ] partition_spec [PURGE]
```

Now if `.trash` folder gets full your cluster will be in unhealthy state. Not sure if the deletion process will fail thought.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

DROP TABLE IF EXIST partition

Comment: i do not intend to drop the table.